# New line spacing not working in jquery preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my form I can click a preview button and it shows me a out putted view.

Because I use `replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")` it replaces the one that are around the br and unable to view new lines. I do not want it to replace the ones around br.

[image]

> **Question:** How is it possible to not touch the  less than < and greater than > around the br tag in side the pre?

Codepen Code [View](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/amxzax)

Codepen Full [View](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/full/amxzax/)

Script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.preview').html($('#question').val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));

        var str = $('.preview pre').html();
        $('.preview pre').html(str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"));

        $('pre').each(function(i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title">Create A New Question</h1>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Title</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2">Question</label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<textarea name="question" id="question"  class="form-control" rows="10">
Testing Question Editor  

<pre>
<div class="test">
</div>
</pre>  
</textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-lg-2"></label>
<div class="col-lg-10">
<div class="preview"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
<div class="btn-group text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="preview-question" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? When there is a `<br>` inside `<pre>`, in the output to change the line and not show `<br>` ? Or when there isn't a `<br>` inside `<pre>`, in the output to change the line and not add a `<br>` ?

Comment: @Thanasis when  I replace the less than < and greater than > in pre it replaces the ones around the br? How can I stop that from happening.

Comment: try using the regex: /<[~b ]/g, it will take all < signs which does not have a b or a space after them, I think this is what u want

Comment: @AlonAlexander How do I add it to my code?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 where you have the replace(/</g) replace it with what I wrote. In case you don't know: everything between the 2 '/'-s is a regex expression and you can find a lot of material about regex online. It will surely solve your problem. I hope this helped